# Как парсить дату с русскими словами (месяцами)?

Tags: ruby

Есть даты вида:

> 7 ноября 2006

Пробовал так:

```
begin
    date = Date.parse('7 ноября 2006')
rescue ArgumentError
    date = nil
end
```

Но на выходе получаю null.

Как их парсить на Ruby?

Comment: Встроенного решения, скорее всего, нет. Но если у вас зафиксирован формат, можно сделать find&replace (`String#gsub`) чтобы перевести на английский, и проблема решена. Если напишете, можете опубликовать ответом сами :)

Comment: @D-side да, решил проблему сам, но почти также. Менял не на название месяца на английском, а на номер месяца. Но ваше решени тоже верное. Даже, наверно, лучше, из-за ненадобности чего-то типа `.grep(' ', '/')`.

Comment: Вы ответ-то не забудьте оставить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно заменить английское слово (название месяца) на русское с помощью `.grep()`, как посоветовал @D-side.

Но мне нужно было получить исключительно числа, поэтому я все той же функцией `.grep()` заменил название месяца на его номер, соединил и парсанул `Date.parse`.